# Why did this character have super-human abilities?

Tags: silent-sea

**I cannot ask this question without spoilers, so I am just going to make a crucial bit of initial information. Please do not read if you do not want to be spoilered otherwise.**

In [*The Silent Sea*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt11570202/), the protagonists encounter

> a girl named Luna

whose body is able to process the otherwise poisonous "lunar water".

While this resistance against the "lunar water" is explained as the result of genetic tinkering specifically to reach this goal.

However, Luna is shown to possess far superhuman strength and agility (ripping out a grown man's arm, lifting up another man to the ceiling and strangling (?) him with bare hands, and overall executing fast jumps along walls and ceiling).

> In the end, it is even revealed she can live outside of Balhae Station without a spacesuit, so she even seems to be resistant to the extreme heat/cold of the moon, the radiation, and doesn't need to breathe.

Is there any behind-the-scenes commentary whether that was for some reason a general feature used for the clones Luna belonged to, or whether the authors had any other reason in mind for that?